# javascript array looping to a table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a table with 2 columns, the header is for Names and Salaries,
then i'm trying to loop an array with names and another one for salaries, but it doesn't come out in order, they fill the first column only(Name)

```
<table border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <script>
                var employeeName = ["Tom", "John", "Jack", "Sam", "Sarah", "Rachel", "Rick", "Sean", "Joe"];
                for(var i = 0 ; i < employeeName.length ; i++)
                {
                    document.write("<tr>");
                    document.write("<td>" + employeeName[i] + "</td>");

                }
                var employeeSalary = ["1000", "1500", "2000", "5000", "2500", "3000", "3500", "2500", "1750"];
                for(var e = 0 ; e < employeeSalary.length ; e++)
                {

                    document.write("<td>" + employeeSalary[e] + "</td>");
                    document.write("</tr>");
                }


            </script>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should avoid `document.write` if you can. You should get a reference to the `tbody` element, build the complete string, then using `innerHTML` to add that string as the content of the `tbody`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is, that you store name and salary in different arrays. It was better to store both values in an object and the objects in one list. But according to your given structure you have to solve it as follows:

```
<table border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <script>
                var employeeName = ["Tom", "John", "Jack", "Sam", "Sarah", "Rachel", "Rick", "Sean", "Joe"];
                var employeeSalary = ["1000", "1500", "2000", "5000", "2500", "3000", "3500", "2500", "1750"];

                for(var i = 0 ; i < employeeName.length ; i++)
                {
                    document.write("<tr>");
                    document.write("<td>" + employeeName[i] + "</td><td>" + employeeSalary[i] + "</td>");
                    document.write("</tr>");
                }


            </script>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the reply to your enquiry in the comments below. If you want to solve your problem with an array of objects I'd suggest this:

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Salary
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <script>
            const employees = [
                  {name:"Tom", salary:"1000"}, 
                  {name:"John", salary:"1500"}, 
                  {name:"Jack", salary:"2000"}, 
                  {name:"Sam", salary:"5000"}, 
                  {name:"Sarah", salary:"2500"}, 
                  {name:"Rachel", salary:"3000"}, 
                  {name:"Rick", salary:"3500"}, 
                  {name:"Sean", salary:"2500"}, 
                  {name:"Joe", salary:"1750"}
                  ];

            employees.forEach( element => {
                document.write("<tr>");
                document.write("<td>" + element.name + "</td><td>" + element.salary + "</td>");
                document.write("</tr>");
            });
        </script>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it worked thanks a lot, would you mind showing me how to do it the way you referred to ?

Comment: Here you go. Just added an edit with the formerly suggested object-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put `name` and `salary` in column then Just iterate through 1 loop. Inside this loop create the new `tr` and set the value `name` and `salary` in new `td` of this `tr`.

```html
<table border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <script>
              var employeeSalary = ["1000", "1500", "2000", "5000", "2500", "3000", "3500", "2500", "1750"];
                var employeeName = ["Tom", "John", "Jack", "Sam", "Sarah", "Rachel", "Rick", "Sean", "Joe"];
                for(var i = 0 ; i < employeeName.length ; i++)
                {
                    document.write("<tr>");
                    document.write("<td>" + employeeName[i] + "</td>"); 
                    document.write("<td>" + employeeSalary[i] + "</td>");
                    document.write("</tr>");
                }
              
               


            </script>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array of employees, and create a `tr` for each one. Next I would append that row to the `tbody` element.

Doing this will avoid having two loops.

```js
var employeeName = ["Tom", "John", "Jack", "Sam", "Sarah", "Rachel", "Rick", "Sean", "Joe"];
var employeeSalary = ["1000", "1500", "2000", "5000", "2500", "3000", "3500", "2500", "1750"];

let employeeInfo = employeeName.map((name, key) => `<tr><td>${name}</td><td>${employeeSalary[key]}</td></tr>`)

document.querySelector('table tbody').innerHTML = employeeInfo.join('')
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to have them in column wise, you should have both names and salaries in same loop like below

```
var employeeName = ["Tom", "John", "Jack", "Sam", "Sarah", "Rachel", "Rick", "Sean", "Joe"]; 

var employeeSalary = ["1000", "1500", "2000", "5000", "2500", "3000", "3500", "2500", "1750"]; 

for(var i = 0 ; i < employeeName.length ; i++) 
{ document.write("<tr>");
 document.write("<td>" + employeeName[i] + "</td>"); 
document.write("<td>" + employeeSalary[i] + "</td>");
document.write("</tr>"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let employees = [{name: "Tom", salary: 1000}...]
let table = ["<table>"];
for(let employee of employees) { 
    table.push("<tr>"); 
    table.push("<td>" + employee.name + "</td>"); 
    table.push("<td>" + employee.salary+ "</td>");
    table.push("</tr>"); 
}
table.push("</table>");
document.write(table.join());
```